# Prove the trigonometric identities $\cot(x)- \cot(2x) =\csc(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove $\cot(x) - \cot(2x) =\csc(2x)$.
I start to solve from LHS, and change all the terms into $\sin$ and $\cos$, but I could not prove it into $\csc(2x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, $$\cot x-\cot 2x$$
$$=\frac{1}{\tan x}-\frac{1}{\tan 2x}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\tan x}-\frac{1-\tan^2x}{2\tan x}$$ $$=\frac{2-1+\tan^2 x}{2\tan x}$$
$$=\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{2\tan x}$$ $$=\frac{\sec^2 x}{2\tan x}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2\tan x \cos^2 x}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2\sin x\cos x}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\sin 2x}$$ $$=\color{blue}{\csc 2x}$$

Answer (score 3):

We could use the difference identity for $\sin(\alpha - \beta)$. Alternatively (since I can never remember those identities), we could go the longer route and use double angle identities:
\begin{align*}
\cot x - \cot 2x
&= \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} - \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x} \\
&= \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} - \frac{2\cos^2 x - 1}{2\sin x \cos x} \\
&= \frac{(2\cos^2 x) - (2\cos^2 x - 1)}{2\sin x \cos x} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sin x \cos x} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sin 2x} \\
&= \csc 2x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\cot{x}-\cot{2x}&={2\cos^2{x}-\cos{2x}\over 2\sin{x}\cos{x}}\\
&={1+\cos{2x}-\cos{2x}\over 2\sin{x}\cos{x}}\\
&={1\over \sin{2x}}\\
&=\csc{2x}
\end{align}$$

Where we have use the two identitities $\sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}$ and $2\cos^2{x}-1=\cos{2x}$

Answer (score 0):

So we wish to show that $\cot{x}-\cot{2x}=\csc{2x}$. Rearranging the equation we can show $\cot{2x}+\csc{2x}=\cot{x}$.

Thus we have
$$\cot{2x}=\frac{1}{\tan{2x}}=\frac{1-\tan^2{x}}{2\tan{x}}
$$
and
$$\csc{2x}=\frac{1}{\sin{2x}}=\frac{1}{2\sin{x}\cos{x}}\equiv \frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}}}{\frac{2\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}}=\frac{\sec^2{x}}{2\tan{x}}
$$
Thus via the identity $\sec^2{x}-\tan^2{x}=1 $ we have

$$\cot{2x}+\csc{2x}=\frac{1-\tan^2{x}}{2\tan{x}}+\frac{\sec^2{x}}{2\tan{x}}
$$

$$=\frac{1+\sec^2{x}-\tan^2{x}}{2\tan{x}}
$$

$$=\frac{2}{2\tan{x}}
$$

$$=\cot{x}
$$

(Via the identities there are a plethora of ways to solve it!)